# Input field which allows ip

Tags: android

I want to make a text field which will allow me to input only IP Adresses in the format x.x.x.x
Where x can not be more than 255.
I found some coding which allows me only upto x.x, can you please help me on this?
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this code

```
 public class IPAddressFormatValidator{
    private Pattern pattern;
    private Matcher matcher;
    private static final String IPADDRESS_PATTERN =
        "^([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
        "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
        "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
        "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$";

    public IPAddressFormatValidator(){
      pattern = Pattern.compile(IPADDRESS_PATTERN);
    }
    public boolean validate(final String ipAddress){         
      matcher = pattern.matcher(ipAddress);
      return matcher.matches();            
    }
    }
```

Comment: so how i am gonna connect this class to my textfield?

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressior. eg for ip address:

```
 String ipAdress = "(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)";
```

Or you can use 4 different text view with max 255 and then combine them later.

Answer (score 1):

Use pattern matcher

```
public final static boolean isValidIp(CharSequence target)
{
    if (target == null) return false;
    else return android.util.Patterns.IP_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of regular expression for IP Address validation.

((2|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9])[.]){3}((2|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]))

You can refer this link. http://gskinner.com/RegExr/